# What exactly are the requirements for the founder badge?

Tags: support, badges, area-51, founder-badge

Specifically: If a proposal reached the commit phase and I wasn't following it but committed to it, and that proposal then made it to launch, will I get the badge or not?

What falls under the category of **participated**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [badges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges) page states:

> **Founder** Participated in the definition, commitment, and beta phases of a successful site

So you have to have "followed", "committed" and been a private beta user (got the beta badge) on a site that has graduated.

I don't know whether it also needs for you to have supplied sample questions and voted on other questions during the definition phase. I haven't followed a site I didn't do this on.

Comment: Full requirements were detailed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66508/founder-badge-requirements-on-area-51. I'm not sure which direction to close as duplicate, though. This is older but obviously lacks the answer... a merge is probably fairly appropriate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you must supply sample questions that receive on/off topic votes as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is (now) a more detailed description of the steps in [a later question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66508/143601).  It says:

> The requirements are:
>
> 1. Followed the proposal
> 2. Proposed an example question during the definition phase that got an on-topic or off-topic vote
> 3. Committed to the proposal
> 4. Followed through on commitment during the beta

For reference, it and all other badges are documented in the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/143601).