# Founder badge requirements on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, founder-badge

I have a profile on Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/12727/paresh-mayani

Just now, I checked the [badges link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges). There, I saw that the Founder badge has not been awarded to anyone. **I would like to know what exactly  the requirements for the "Founder" badge are.**

I have already checked the [Founder badge info](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/204/founder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The founder badge should be working now.

The requirements are:

1. Followed the proposal
2. Proposed an example question during the definition phase that got an on-topic or off-topic vote
3. Committed to the proposal
4. Followed through on commitment during the beta

6 users earned it for the Web Applications launch.  See http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/204/founder

Comment: what if you tag as "status completed" , any reputation will i get ?

Comment: @Paresh status tags are used by moderators to indicate the status of feature-requests / bugs.  They have no effect on reputation.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48315/why-are-some-tags-colored-formatted-differently-in-meta-stackoverflow-com

Comment: i just wanted to know, and really glad that i have helped you to improve atleast small point

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, because the badge requirements are displayed right on the page that you linked. They are:

> Participated in the definition, commitment, and beta phases of a successful site. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Did you not see the description, or did you not understand some part of it? Please add a comment or edit your question if I haven't answered your question.

EDIT:
I'm not an admin, so any definition I put forth would be pure speculation. However, I can explain the reason that nobody has a Founder badge yet. Only one site has made it out of the beta phase so far. Based on some of the [discussion at its per-site meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com), I don't think the team considers it "a successful site" just yet. It's kind of hard to participate in all the phases of a successful site if there are no successful sites, eh?

Comment: I think the question is what exactly is required to "participate" in the various stages, surely some should have done this like he who proposed the web apps site.

Comment: @googletorp, ah, that makes sense.

Comment: but i didnt understand that requirement description for Founder badge, and yet noone is having that badge